# How do I generate code like for using a C macro? #for?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, code-generation

Is there are C macro like the `for` loop, that can generate code for me to use functions?

for example:

I have

```
SetSystem1();
SetSystem2();
SetSystem3();
...
SetSystem100();
```

can I write

```
#for index = 0 to 100
    SetSystem##index();
#endfor
```

so the system will generate `SetSystem1` to `SetSystem100`?

Is there are some macro can create code like this?

I can't use array pointer to the C library.

Comment: *"I can't use array pointer to the c lib."* Why not? Boost.Preprocessor can do this, but it's probably a bad idea, since you can use a function pointer array.

Comment: Most likely the best advice is "Don't.". But maybe we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem So please explain what you want to achieve by using a pre-processor feature you hope to exist but more or less invented.

Comment: The real question is why you have 100 functions named SetSystem1 .. SetSystem100. This is an instant no-go in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such facility in the C preprocessor. Given the complexity of this tool and its shortcomings, there is no chance that it be extended in future versions of the C Standard.

You can use another tool to generate the text and include that in your source file. Here is an example using the `bash` shell:

```
for i in {1..100} ; do echo "    SetSystem$i();" ; done
```

Alternately, using the `tr` utility:

```
echo "SetSystem"{1..100}"();" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Or as commented by *Eric Postpischil*, using `jot` on BSD systems:

```
jot -w '    SetSystem%d();' 100
```

But *KamilCuk* found a simpler and most elegant solution:

```
printf "    SetSystem%d();\n" {1..100}
```

Advanced programmers' editors have powerful macro systems that will enable you to produce the same output interactively.

Comment: `jot -w '    SetSystem%d();' 100`

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes `jot` is a good tool, but available mostly on BSD systems. Too bad `echo "    SetSystem"{1..100}"();\n"` does not handle `\n` nicely.

Comment: `printf "SetSystem%d();\n" {1..100}`

Comment: @KamilCuk: amazing!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there are some macro can create code like this?

No, not really. Even if you want to create such macro, you have to spell out all possibilities - it will take 100 macros for 100 cases.

You can use libraries that come with such maros, like `p99` https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/p99/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for_gae3eb0e3a5216300874ed6cb9abc170ce.html#gae3eb0e3a5216300874ed6cb9abc170ce :

```
#define P00_SEP(NAME, I, REC, RES) REC; RES
#define P00_VASSIGN(NAME, X, I)  SetSystem##I()
P99_FOR(A, 101, P00_SEP, P00_VASSIGN, , );
```

Or `boost` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html :

```
#define DECL(z, I, text) SetSystem##I();
BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, 100, DECL, )
```

You can also use some external preprocessor additionally to C preprocessor. For example with `m4`:

```
# forloop.m4, from documentation
divert(`-1')
# forloop(var, from, to, stmt)
define(`forloop',
  `pushdef(`$1', `$2')_forloop(`$1', `$2', `$3', `$4')popdef(`$1')')
define(`_forloop',
  `$4`'ifelse($1, `$3', ,
    `define(`$1', incr($1))_forloop(`$1', `$2', `$3', `$4')')')
divert`'dnl

forloop(`i', `1', `100', `dnl
`      SetSystem'i`();
'')
```

or with php:

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) echo "SystemOut".$i."();\n"; ?>
```

or with Python Jinja2:

```
{% for i in range(1, 100) %}
      SystemOut{{ i }}();
{% endfor %}
```